# Can we make changes in the IAM policies of google by using some other's access/bearer token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-iam

I am working on the GmailwebhookTrigger in which I am getting the notification for the new emails. I want to add multiple members into my topic means want to get notifications for multiple people on my topic. To do that I have to add that member as pub/sub subscriber into my iampolicy console. I am not able to do that it is giving me following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

by hitting the following api

```
https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gmailwebhookserver:getIamPolicy
```

also if I tried to hit the following other api I get the same error

```
https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/gmailwebhookserver:setIamPolicy
```

I have done everything provided in the documentation to fix that, but I am not able to do so. But when I am adding external user as owner to project in my IamConsole at following url `https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/ia?project=testProject`, I am able to achieve what I am willing to achieve. But that thing I have to do manually by doing so I am giving full rights of my project to other users. I think to allow external users to make changes in my cloud iampolicies I need to authenticate external users using my service account. But I don't know how to do that. Suggest me way either to authenticate user with my service account or by any other means, so that I may have to do nothing manually.